# No puedo cambiar el fondo en mi proyecto

Tags: ionic

```css
page-home{

}

.titulo{
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.tapiz{
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      <img src="assets/icon/logo.png" width="130">
      <p class="titulo">Texto</p>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="tapiz">

</ion-content>
```

Les dejo mi home.page.html y mi home.page.scss, el estilo de mi titulo si lo agarra pero el background no, cuando inspecciono el elemento en google chrome me doy cuenta que esta esta linea.... background: var(--ion-background-color,#fff); */... y cuando la desactivo, ya me cambia mi fondo al negro como lo quiero, pero no se donde esta alojado ese estilo. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: ¿qué componente es el que tiene el css que desactivas?

Answer (score 0):

ionic usa sass y como estas usando un componente llamado page-home, todo el sass aplicado a el va entre sus llaves, la forma correcta seria :

```
page-home{

  .titulo{
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .tapiz{
    background-color: #000000 !important;
  }

}
```